# Eloquent - Where Date >= date(now) and whereNull('date')

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I get all items from a table where:

- `endDate` is >= now
- `endDate` is `NULL`
- `published` equals `1`.

This is what I have, but it gives me 0 items:

```php
$items = Items::orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))
  ->where('endDate', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
  ->whereNull('endDate')
  ->where('published', '1')
  ->whereIn('cid', $this->activeId)
  ->orderBy('id')
  ->paginate(4);
```

Comment: why are you including `->where('available', '1')` if you want data with `->where('published', '1')`. May be that is the issue

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use a closure and the `orWhereNull()`:

```
->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('endDate', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
      ->orWhereNull('endDate');
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do with two closure `where` and `orWhere`:

```
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('endDate', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
      ->orWhere('endDate',NULL);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using both condition , which never give result

```
->where('endDate', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
->whereNull('endDate')
```

Try to use `orWhere`

Comment: if i use: ->where('saleEndDate', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
            ->orWhereNull('saleEndDate'), this will give me all items from table where date is < as date(now)